# wp_query ignoring custom post_status

Tags: wp-query, post-status

I have a custom post status called 'dead.' I am trying to create a wp_query to show all posts for a custom taxonomy. If I specify 'any' for the post_status I do get published posts and my 'dead' post_status posts. Likewise, if I set the post_status parameter to only 'dead' I do get just those posts. But, if I try to set the post_status to show both published and dead post_status posts via an array I can only get the published ones.

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'dead'),
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'linktypes',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => '15'
        ),
    )
);  
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
```

Does WordPress not allow you to specify both standard and custom post_statuses in an array like this? Or am I just doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**: As recommended, I am adding the code I use to create the custom post_status (as well as the code to add it to the admin screen and quick edit screen just in case that might be relevant.

```
function custom_post_status() {
    register_post_status( 'dead', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Dead', 'post' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Dead <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Dead <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_status' );


function my_post_submitbox_misc_actions() {
    global $post;
    //only when editing a post
    if( $post->post_type == 'post' ){
        // custom post status: dead
        $complete = '';
        $label = '';   

        if( $post->post_status == 'dead' ){
            $complete = ' selected=\"selected\"';
            $label = '<span id=\"post-status-display\"> Dead</span>';
        }

        echo '<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("select#post_status").append("<option value=\"publish\" selected=\"publish\">Publish</option>");
            $("select#post_status").append("<option value=\"dead\" '.$complete.'>Dead</option>");
            $(".misc-pub-section label").append("'.$label.'");
        });
        </script>';
    }
}
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'my_post_submitbox_misc_actions' );


function rudr_status_into_inline_edit() { 
    echo "<script>
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery( 'select[name=\"_status\"]' ).append( '<option value=\"dead\">Dead</option>' );
    });
    </script>";
}
add_action('admin_footer-edit.php','rudr_status_into_inline_edit');
```

**UPDATE #2**: I added `print_r($my_query->request);` to see the WP_Query request SQL and this is what I see.

using `'post_status' => array('dead')`:

```
SELECT [...] AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'dead')) GROUP BY [...]
```

using `'post_status' => array('publish','dead')`:

```
SELECT [...] AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY [...]
```

using `'post_status' => array('any')`:

```
SELECT [...] AND ((wp_posts.post_status <> 'trash' AND wp_posts.post_status <> 'auto-draft')) GROUP BY [...]
```

using `'post_status' => array('publish','future')`:

```
SELECT [...]  AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future')) GROUP BY [...]
```

Comment: You request via `post_type` only the type `post`. Have you only enhanced the custom post status? If not, you need to add also this post type, like `'post_type' => array( 'post', 'dead' )`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and yes, 'dead' is only a custom status not a custom post type.  So, I only want posts. As mentioned, if I set the post_status to only 'dead' I do indeed get just the dead status posts so it's not that the post_status parameter cannot recognize my 'dead' status at all. Only when I try to make it part of an array of post statuses.

Comment: Try runing the code without `tax_query`, maybe you dont have any posts with `dead` status and with that taxonomy. Also the `new wp_query( $args )` should be `new WP_Query( $args )` (Even though classes are case insensitive, this is still good practice).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I will note the case issue. As I mentioned, there are indeed dead posts of my custom taxonomy, which are returned when I only set the post_status to 'dead' or 'any.' But, if I include 'dead' in an array of choices (as in the code I posted), then they no longer get returned.

Comment: Possibly a long-shot, but it might help us to help you if you can also post the code you use to register your custom status...seems like the default parameters would be fine, but you never know, we might spot a clue there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my post to include that code.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Your code is working as expected when I copy and test locally.  I am testing w/o the tax query, however.  Using the array for the `post_status` query param works fine like this: `'post_status' => array('publish', 'dead')`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and effort to do that. I just tried removing the tax query to see if it works for me like it did for you but, alas, still having the problem. I have multiple custom taxonomies so removing the tax query produces different numbers of 'dead' posts but none are being returned unless I query for it alone or query 'any' for post_status.

Comment: There is likely a plugin or something in your theme causing the problem.  Are you filtering these posts in another context that isn't properly scoped?  Any `pre_get_posts` hooks, for example?  Recommend switching themes and deactivating plugins temporarily to debug.

Comment: Just noticed your latest edit above.  Something is modifying your query before it runs is my guess.  See comment above for debug suggestions.  Switching themes and deactivating plugins temporarily will eliminate any other code that could be filtering your query before it runs (like with `pre_get_posts`)

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks. I will try that and see.

Comment: I switched to the standard WordPress theme and deactivated all plugins but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Mojamba, Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the reason was that I was running the query before registering the post status. So the post status was not registered and thus ignored in WP_Query